# How can I determine the coordinate representation of Killing fields from the structure constants?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose I have a (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ and some Lie subgroup $G \subset \text{Iso}(M)$ acting on $M$. Then $G$ determines a Lie algebra $\frak g$ of Killing vector fields $V_i$ on $M$ with structure equations
$$
[V_i, V_j] = c_{ij}^k V_k.
$$
In particular, by the Frobenius theorem, $\frak g$ determines a foliation of $M$ where every point $p$ can be surrounded by a coordinate chart $(U, x^i)$ s.t. the leaf $S$ passing through $p$ has the form $x^j = 0$ for all $j \ge k$. By definition, the tangent space of $S$ consists of the $V_i$ Killing fields, so we can find smooth functions $a_i^j$ on $S$ s.t.
$$
V_i = a_i^j \partial_j. 
$$
It seems to me that plugging this into the structure equations results in a system of first order PDEs that is hard to solve, so we must somehow reduce the complexity of the problem by changing coordinates on $S$. Is there a way to find a coordinate transformation that ensures some of the $V_i$'s are equal to $\partial_i$? I know something like this is possible when all the $V_i$'s commute, but if only some of them commute I am not so sure. Otherwise, is there some methodical way to express the $V_i$'s in terms of the $\partial_i$'s?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this depends on some more Frobenius integrability conditions. For $V_i = \partial_i$, I think we need something like $V_j , j\neq i$ spanning an integrable hyperplane distribution of $\mathfrak{g}$ i.e. closed under Lie bracket (which is trivially true if $\mathfrak{g}$ is abelian). I don't believe such a setup is guaranteed except locally. Note: I am writing this a little quickly and I might have the details a little off

Comment: @Callum local results are okay. I am mostly having trouble showing that one can reparametrize each leaf in the foliation while keeping the coordinate change non-singular.

Comment: Simply pick your coordinates and set $V_i =\partial_i$. Locally there is no obstruction to this. Such a (smooth family of) transformation will not be singular since it sends a basis to another basis at each point. Of course you can leave the coordinates which are transverse to the foliation alone.